# unable to get spring-social-showcase-boot working due to facebook scope?

Tags: spring, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I am following the instructions provided here to get [spring-social-showcase-boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-showcase-boot) running in my local.

This is the error I get when I try to authenticate using facebook. The error is clear that `read_stream` scope is invalid.

[image]

But I am unable to figure where this `scope` is configured in the `spring-social-showcase-boot` example.

Any help to fix this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem. You can change the scopes you request by modifying the 'scope' form field in  [/src/main/resources/templates/connect/facebookConnect.html](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/blob/master/spring-social-showcase-boot/src/main/resources/templates/connect/facebookConnect.html#L15).

Specifically I removed 'read_stream' and just had 'email' as the value of that form input.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, I no longer get the "Invalid Scopes: read_stream" error message. Did it not work for  you?

Comment: I had the same problem but it was because I've tried some two years ago spring-social and I still had the authorization in facebook. Delete the old one to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Just change:
./admin/sources/classes/facebook/connect.php:   public $extendedPerms = array( 'email', 'read_stream', 'publish_stream' );

to be:
./admin/sources/classes/facebook/connect.php:   public $extendedPerms = array( 'email' );